# Current day , month, year from datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I have the below piece of code for getting me the current date.

```
$('#txtSelectedDate').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    currentText: "Today:" + $.datepicker.formatDate('dd mm yy', new Date())
});
```

How do i extract to `alert` day, month, year separately.

Comment: Would you let me know it with the syntax !?, JS and datepicker is a lil new to me. Thanks

Comment: which datepicker you are using?

Comment: I think you should do something like 
`var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd mm yy', new Date());
 alert("Day:" + data.getDay() ...);`

But I didn't checked if these methods are available

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: '<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>                                                                                     
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>'   is what I make use of

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = new Date();

var date = d.getDate();

var month=d.getMonth()+1;
// we are adding 1 to getMonth Method, becoz it will return 0 to 11

var year=d.getFullYear();
```

**Hope it helps..**

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

```
var today = new Date();
console.log(today.getDate());
console.log(today.getMonth());
console.log(today.getFullYear());
```

SoF reference
[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the datepicker with the altField option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
   altField: "#actualDate"
});
```

Initialize the datepicker with the altFormat option specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
   altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

Please refer for more detail:-

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

So after looking on the web you can do that :

```
var date = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd mm yy', new Date());
alert("Day:" + date.getDay() + "month:" + date.getMonth() + "year:" + date.getFullYear());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
You can use the [onSelect](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect) event

```html
<html>

<head>
    
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <input type='text' class='date'>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function ($) {

            $("#dataPicker").datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dateText) {
                    display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
                    alert("Day " + (new Date(dateText)).getDate() + " Month: " + (new Date(dateText)).getMonth() + " Year: " +  (new Date(dateText)).getFullYear())
                }
            }).on("change", function () {
                display("Got change event from field");
            });

            function display(msg) {
                $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
            }

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dataPicker">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this way

```
 $('#txtSelectedDate').datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        currentText: "Today:" + $.datepicker.formatDate('dd mm yy', new Date()),
       onSelect: function(){
                var day = $("#txtSelectedDate").datepicker('getDate').getDate(); 
    alert(day);                
                var month = $("#txtSelectedDate").datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;  
    alert(month);           
                var year = $("#txtSelectedDate").datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
               alert(year);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, but I'm trying to get Today's date info. What you suggested will provide the selected date from datepicker

Comment: @shwink do u want to alert today day,month,year or print ?

Comment: Yes that correct. I need to check the selected date should not be earlier than today.